# Group by in a denormalized table

Tags: sql-server, performance, denormalization

We have a table with denormalized data that stores events with, among others, the following fields:
ProductId | ProductName | SubcategoryId

They are directly dependent on each other so for a particular productid there can be exactly one value for Productname and subcategoryid.
Since we store events we have many rows that will contain the same information with respect to the three fields above.

We are now designing a query to get the unique productid, productname and subcategoryid.
These queries will return the same entities:

```
select ProductId from VisitEvents
group by ProductId
```

as this one:

```
select productid, productname, subcategoryid from visitevents
group by productid, productname, subcategoryid
```

However the latter is orders of magnitude slower.
Is there a way to project other fields than what is being grouped on in the first query?

Comment: Use [`Distinct`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) without `Group By`

Comment: The speed issues could have to do with indexing. If you have a non-clustered index on ProductID then then it could just pull that out without needing to hit the clustered index. Also, sorting (which is required for grouping) is very processor and memory intensive.Your sort may not have a big enough memory grant and be spilling to disk. Reviewing your execution plans may indicate issues (e.g., yellow ! marks indicating problems). Also if you `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;` before running, it will give you a good summary of how your data is being read from disk.

Comment: You have suggestions. The short answer is no absent a change in DDL. Indexing might help. A materialized view might help. Perhaps now is a good time to review the reasons that lead to denormalization - because that is the actual cause. One more thing to consider. Most queries need to be sorted to be useful - your query has no ORDER BY clause and therefore has no defined order. If order is important, your query MUST have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: We have a clustered columnstore index on the table so more indices might not help. 
@MostafaArmandi, I've tried distinct and that gives me the exact same performance.

Answer (score 0):

I put in a comment about re potential causes for the speed issues (mainly probably due to the increased reads and processing required for sorting).

However, my main understanding of your question is

- Your data is really just grouped on productid, but because it's denormalised, it has other columns directly related to productid
- Because you are grouping on all three fields, it is slow - and you want it to go faster by just grouping on productid

**Answer 1: Indexing**

If you put an index on those columns, it will already be pre-sorted. However, my guess is that your indexes are pretty intensive already so more indexes may cause problems. If not, then please try just adding an index over all 3 fields, or if some are too large (e.g., nvarchar(4000)), then an index on the remaining fields, and 'include' the large fields.

**Adjusting the query**

For these, we accept that we'll have to do the sort within the query. The question is how to reduce the processing and/or reads.

Without stats and/or execution plans, this can be hard - but here are some suggestions.

This first approach below, I believe, will *not* really work, but is worth a try.

```
select productid, MAX(productname) as productname, MAX(subcategoryid) as subcategoryid
from visitevents
group by productid
```

I hope what you see I'm trying to do there - reducing the group-by to just one field. However, as it still needs to do sorts to get the max values, it may still be slow (although as they are not being sorted together, it may be a bit faster).

An alternative is to get a sort/group on productid and get *any* of the corresponding values (you don't care which). One way to do this is

```
; WITH cte AS 
  (select productid, productname, subcategoryid,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY productid) AS rn
   from visitevents
  )
SELECT productid, productname, subcategoryid
FROM cte
WHERE cte.rn = 1
```

For the above, it gets all the data, sorts it by productid then (kinda randomly) assigns row numbers to each row within that group. It then just gets all the first rows.

It's ugly. It kind of abuses the windowed function (`PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY productid`???) By definition this ORDER BY does nothing, but is included because you must have an ORDER BY within a ROW_NUMBER.

And doing nothing is what you want - don't want to spend CPU cycles on additional sorts. So hopefully it may help.